# Don't Able To Download Video using ytdl-core, express and nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios, youtube-dl, ytdl

I am trying to download youtube video using [ytdl-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-core). I made simple express server for backend and made frontend UI with nextjs. From my nextjs app, I made a post request to express server using axios.

```
Axios.post("http://localhost:3030/ytdonwload", {url : url}).then((response)=>{
            fileDownload(response.data, `video.mp4`);
})
```

In express server, I receive youtube url from req.body and send response like this.

```
app.post("/ytdonwload",(req, res)=>{
    res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="video.mp4"');
    ytdl(req.body.url).pipe(res)
})
```

To download file in frontend, I used [js-file-download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-file-download). The video is downloaded but it's not playable.

I really don't have idea what to do.

Comment: Which headers do you provide in express response? I